# Using .filter to search array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I was programming with Node.js regarding some customer data. At one point I was reviewing my code and I realized I had written something like this:

```
for(var contract of contractData)
{
   var customer = customerData.filter(customer => customer.customerCode === contract.customerCode)[0];
}
```

So I have an array of some contracts and an array of some customers. I need to loop throught the contracts and find the correct customer for each contract by comparing the `customerCode` in the contract to the `customerCode` of a customer.

I for some reason thought that using the filter method like so at least looks the most clean solution, but I began wondering **if it is a good idea to use it like that, especially when I know the result will always be an array with length of one**, which is I am using the [0] in the end.

Lets not cling into other details such as why the contracts and the customers are not indexed by their customerCodes or why am I not using a database for this. I am only interested in the usage of `.filter` this way and if it makes any sense to use it like this. If this is not a good way, what would be the better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when you only want to identify the *one* element that fulfills the test in an array, the appropriate method to use is `.find`, which will return that one element (or `undefined` if there are no matching elements):

```
for(var contract of contractData) {
  var customer = customerData.find(customer => customer.customerCode === contract.customerCode);
}
```

The arguments and evaluation is the same as `filter`, except that just one element is returned. Note, though, that `.find` is ES6, so include a polyfill to support obsolete browsers.

Comment: Excellent! I wasn't aware of `.find`, though I had a hunch something was off with the `.filter` solution. Thank you! I'll mark this as solved when I can. P.S. Browser support does not matter in this case, I'm just writing a node script for myself for some work related thing, but I like to think and learn from all of my solutions.

Answer (score -2):

for browser please keep in mind `[].find()` has very limited browser support only modern browser no ie at all.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=find Click "usage relative". Support is *pretty good* - ES2015 was 3 years ago, after all - and even for ancient browsers, a polyfill is easy.

Comment: The question is tagged node.js…